# Adding an mouse event listener to a bitmap with ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm new to ActionScript 3 (without any experience with Flash development) and I was wondering how I would go about **adding an mouse event listener to a bitmap**? The code works with a sprite, just not with a bitmap. Here is a shortened version of the code I'm trying to run, I hope it makes sense!

```
var fsImageRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("img/fullscreen.png");
var fsImageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
fsImageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fsImageLoaded);
fsImageLoader.load(fsImageRequest);
addChild(fsImageLoader);

function fsImageLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var fsImageLoader:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
    fsImage = Bitmap(fsImageLoader.content);
    fsImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fullScreenClick)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've added the event listener in the line fsImage.addEventListener(...

Now you need to write the function that handles that event, such as:

```
private function fullScreenClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  // do something here
}
```

EDIT: To add a bitmap to a sprite, you can do the following:

```
var sprite: Sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.addChild(fsImage);
addChild(sprite);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I already have a function to handle the event - it works with a sprite or a textfield, just not a bitmap. Is there a way I can make a bitmap act as a sprite?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the bitmap?

Comment: I want to be able to run a mouse event on it. Is there a way I can encapsulate it within a sprite?

Answer (score 7):

You can't add MouseEvents to a bitmap because it is not a descendant of the type InteractiveObject. You will have to wrap it in a Sprite or MovieClip and add Click Listeners to the container.